# Write to csv is omitting first row

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am writing my Hashmap into a csv file with headers using the below piece of code. However, what I notice is that the first data row is not available in the file. I can the headers and all other rows accurately

```
def self.execute_auto_pg_debtors pg_debtors_dt_list

  partition_key = Date.today.prev_day.prev_day.strftime "%Y%m%d"
  csvfilename = "PG_Debtors_" + partition_key + ".CSV"

  pg_debtors_dt_batch = Array.new 
  rowid = 0

  pg_debtors_dt_list.each { |x|
    pg_debtors_details = Hash.new
    pg_debtors_details["Store_Order_Id"] = x['Store_Order_Id']
    pg_debtors_details["Transaction_Id"] = x['Transaction_Id']
    pg_debtors_details["Gateway_Payment_Id"] = x['Gateway_Payment_Id']
    pg_debtors_details["PPS_Id"] = x['PPS_Id']
    pg_debtors_details["Event_Type"] = x['Event_Type']
    pg_debtors_details["Event_Date"] = x['Event_Date']
    pg_debtors_details["Gateway_Name"] = x['Gateway_Name']
    pg_debtors_details["Open_Amount"] = "%f" % x['Open_Amount']
    pg_debtors_details["Invoice_No"] = x['Invoice_No']

    pg_debtors_dt_batch << pg_debtors_details

    rowid += 1
    if rowid == 1
      CSV.open(csvfilename, "w")  do |csv|
        csv << pg_debtors_details.keys# adding header row (column labels)

    end
  else
      CSV.open(csvfilename, "a")  do |csv|
      csv << pg_debtors_details.values# of if/else inside hsh
  end# of hsh's (rows)
end# of csv open
}

  return pg_debtors_dt_batch
end
```

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are writing the headers instead of the first row!

I recommend, that you open the file and iterate through your hash inside the `CSV.open do ... end`

AND do not use a `else` after your `if rowid == 1`. Just execute that for EVERY `values`, so you do not skip data row 1

Answer (score 1):

Even if you check for `rowid`, the `.each` loop is still not aware of it. So, for `rowid == 1`, it will write the headers, but in the next iteration, `x` will point to the second item in `pg_debtors_dt_list`.

To solve it, write your code in the following order:

1. Open the file, and write the headers first.
2. Loop through `pg_debtors_dt_list`, and write subsequent data to the file.

Hope it helps.